# Modal popup window's contents not being rewritten in IE after load

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, popup

I'm trying what should have been a simple operation: when a user clicks a link a modal window pops up that's populated with some appropriate data in a string.  Here's the HTML for the window:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Modal Display Window</title>

</head>
<body>

  <div id="modal_display_block">REPLACE THIS</div>

</body>
</html>
```

And this is the Javascript function that calls and populates the window:

```
function displayCenterBlock(data) {

    DispWin = window.open("modal_window.html", "", 'toolbar=no,status=no,width=300,height=300');

    DispWin.onload = function() {
        DispWin.document.getElementById('modal_display_block').innerHTML = data;
    }

}
```

This works great in every browser I've tried except Internet Explorer. In IE the innerHTML does not get rewritten by the data. Is there some IE-specific trick or tweak I need to apply to get this working in that browser?

Many thanks in advance!

ON EDIT: I've discovered that if I move the element rewrite line out of the onload function it then works fine in IE but not in other browsers. It appears my options are to use some conditional code to rewrite at once for IE and to wait for page load for all other browsers, or to abandon the rewrite element approach and just use a document.write. I get from forum searches people like to discourage document.write but that's looking pretty appealing right now.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, for better or worse this code achieves the goal and appears to work cross browser, even in IE.

```
DispWin = window.open("", "Display", 'toolbar=no,status=no,width=300,height=300');

DispWin.document.open();

DispWin.document.write(data);

DispWin.document.close();

DispWin.focus();
```

I get that document.write can re-write the whole page, and that is sometimes bad, but in this case that is exactly what I want: a single small page displaying only what was passed in the data argument. I can style it inline.